# ajax from framework7 to laravel gives me unauthorized error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.4, html-framework-7

I've been trying to send ajax request to my laravel backend from my framework7 frontend using ajax.

```
$.ajax({
url: 'localhost:8000/server_file/grabtracks',
data: {task: "tracks"},
method: 'get',
async: false,
}).done(function(data) {
   grabbedTracks = data;
});
```

Here is the code on my Laravel 5.4 routes

```
Route::get('/grabtracks', 'HomeController@grab_track');
```

And here is from my controller

```
public function grab_track()
{
    $tracks = Track::all('id','title','location','price','track_file','track_img');
    return response()->json($tracks);
}
```

I've disabled the CSRF tokens for the meantime, but i keep getting 
 [Unauthorized error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xcbK.png) from my request

I'm at a loss, i've tried searching but only angularJS and laravel comes up.

Comment: it's probably you have a `middleware auth` in your controller constructor

Comment: yea thanks! removed it and everything works fine now. Made a new controller without that middleware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably your Controller has `Auth` **middleware** in your constructor remove the middleware and everything should work fine:

So you can remove this instructor or modify it to web auth:

```
public function __construct()
{
     $this->middleware('auth');
}
```